# How to creat a regex for a something like X.0.4472.114 where X is a number?

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex for something from the template:

> X . number . number number number number . number number

or :

> X . number . number number number number . number number number

Where X is a variable that contains a number.

*e.g:*

X = 102

then:

*102.3.2345.234* is a valid *102.3.2345.23* is valid too.

I have tried to use `"[" + X + "]" + "[.]0[.][\\d][\\d][\\d][\\d][.][\\d][\\d]"`, but it's not working

Comment: I don’t understand what the difference is between X and number?

Comment: There is a difference because if X is 34, then:
34.3.2345.234 is valid but 33.3.2345.234 is not

Comment: So you need something like `String pattern = x + "\.\d{1}\.\d{4}.\d{2,3}";`

Comment: temp.matches(X+"\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{4}.\\d{2,3}") Works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the number to start with in a variable `x` then your regex pattern can be constructed as

```
 String pattern = x + "\\.\\d\\.\\d{4}.\\d{2,3}";
```

Comment: temp.matches(chrome+"\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{4}.\\d{2,3}") works for me

Comment: You can omit the `{1}` and double escape the backslashes in Java.